# Secure file upload directly to s3 or server to s3 (from iOS app)

Tags: ios, node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

I need to upload sensitive images to s3 from an iOS app. I'm wondering which option is better:

1. Upload to my server first, then upload to s3.
2. Upload to s3 directly, then upload metadata to my server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to choose option 2, have your user upload directly to S3.  If you use option 1, you have the possibility of your server going away before it can complete the upload to S3 (think autoscaling, where an instance is taken out of service before it can complete).

And while posting links in answers is frowned upon, the solution is explained on the AWS site and will probably change over time.  You will need to make sure that you have the proper policies configured on your bucket, and your instance roles have correct permissions, etc.

Start here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-UsingHTTPPOST.html